# Http request returning xml value but html collection is empty

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

i'm a student ,this is my first post sorry if it is not good.  For a school project made  to discover Ajax i had to use it.
The princip should be simple : populate a  dropdown list, dynamicaly  fill html text fields with informations regarding what is selected in the  dropdown list.
The problem i encounter is that my Http request gives me the xml i need, but when i try to get the length of the HtmlCollections , it says 0 . to me, something wrong happens when  i use element=element.getElementByTag(tagname).
the method i use to execute the sql query i need is working
thanks for the awnsers i've been working for this the whole day and i'm desperately seeking for help.
After hours of research i think i manage to get the informations i want in the xml but after that when i try to link it to the html using  responseXML.getElementsByTagName() , i shows no result in the HTMLcollections, i corrected myself (didnt write responseXML.getElementsByTagName correctly) but it didnt change a thing, maybe i wrote something else wrong?

```js
<?php
require_once ("requeteBaseDonnee.inc.php");

    var_dump($_POST["nomvisiteur"]);
    
    $resultat = getinfoVisiteur($_POST["nomvisiteur"]);
    
?>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<visiteur>
    <nom><?php echo $resultat["VIS_NOM"]?></nom>
    <prenom><?php echo $resultat["Vis_PRENOM"]?></prenom>
    <adresse><?php echo $resultat["VIS_ADRESSE"]?></adresse>
    <codepostal><?php echo $resultat["VIS_CP"]?></codepostal>
    <ville><?php echo $resultat["VIS_VILLE"]?></ville>
    <secteur><?php echo $resultat["SEC_CODE"]?></secteur>
</visiteur>
```

```js
function creerConnexion (){
    var xhr;
    try{
      xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); 
    }
    catch (e){
      xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    return xhr;
}

//adresse du serveur ou localhost pour test
function creerRequete(fichierACharger, infosAEnvoyer, cible){
    alert("hello");
    var xhr = creerConnexion();

    xhr.onreadystatechange  = function(){ 
        if (xhr.readyState  == 4){
            if (xhr.status  == 200){
                switch(cible){
                    case "praticien":
                        afficherInfoPraticien(xhr);
                        break;
                    case "medicament":
                        afficherInfoMediacement(xhr);
                        break;
                    case "visiteur":
                        afficherInfoVisiteur(xhr);
                        break;
                    default:
                         alert("erreur dans le ciblage de la fonction d'affichage des informations.");
                }
                //alert(xhr.responseText);
            } else{
                alert (xhr.status);
            }
        }
    }; 
    xhr.open("POST", fichierACharger, true); 
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.overrideMimeType("application/xml");
    //alert(infosAEnvoyer);
    xhr.send(infosAEnvoyer);
}

function afficherInfoVisiteur(xhr){
     
    alert (xhr.status);
    alert(xhr.responseText);
    alert(document.getElementsByTagName("adresse").length);
    var nom=xhr.reponseXML.getElementsByTagName("nom")[0].innerHTML;
    var prenom=xhr.reponseXML.getElementsByTagName("prenom")[0].innerHTML;
    var adresse=xhr.reponseXML.getElementsByTagName("adresse")[0].innerHTML;
    var cp=xhr.reponseXML.getElementsByTagName("codepostal")[0].innerHTML;
    var secteur=xhr.reponseXML.getElementsByTagName("secteur")[0].innerHTML;
    
    document.getElementById("nom").value=nom;
    document.getElementById("prenom").value=prenom;
    document.getElementById("adresse").value=adresse;
    document.getElementById("cp").value=cp;
    document.getElementById("codesecteur").value=secteur;
      alert("ok");
    
    }
```

```html
            <select name="nomVisiteur" onchange="alert(this.value);creerRequete('getInfoVisiteur.php','nomvisiteur='+this.value ,'visiteur');">
                        <?php
                        

                        // Loop through the query results, outputing the options one by one
                        while ($row = $nom->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                        echo "<option value='" . $row['VIS_NOM'] ."'>" . $row['VIS_NOM'] ."</option>";
                        }

                            echo '</select>';// Close your drop down box
                  
                  
                  //var_dump(getnumdudepartement($_POST['Departement']));
                            ?>

        <label class="titre">NOM :</label><input type="text" size="25"  id="nom" class="zone" />
        <label class="titre">PRENOM :</label><input type="text" size="50" id="prenom" class="zone" />
        <label class="titre">ADRESSE :</label><input type="text" size="50"  id="adresse"  class="zone" />
        <label class="titre">CP :</label><input type="text" size="5" id="cp" class="zone" />
        <label class="titre">VILLE :</label><input type="text" size="30"  id="ville" class="zone" />
        <label class="titre">SECTEUR :</label><input type="text" size="1" id="codesecteur"  class="zone" />
        <label class="titre">&nbsp;</label><input class="zone"type="button" value="<"></input><input class="zone"type="button" value=">"></input>
```

Comment: You've done a reasonable job of outlining the problem however without posting the relevant code there isn't much anyone can do to help at this point

Comment: Don't get too frustrated , there is a learning curve to how to ask good questions, but posting code as images is not a good practice. See: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: For the JS part , i did only put the function i use : 
function afficherInfoVisiteur(xhr) , the other 2 are in the code but i'm not concerned by them , it is for the 2 other members of my group

Comment: Only issue I see is `alert(document.getElementsByTagName("adresse").length);` should be looking in the xml document not the page document ... `alert(xhr.reponseXML.getElementsByTagName("adresse").length);`

Comment: when i do so the alert doesnt even show up

Comment: Using `alert()` is a horrible debugging tool. Using `console.log()` is far better since you can pass objects as well and expand them in browser dev tools console (F12)

Comment: Example of more modern fetch() transport for your xml https://plnkr.co/edit/3ZYj9Twu7vQKzgkR?open=lib%2Findex.html&preview

Answer (score -1):

```
xhr.reponseXML.getElementsByTagName("nom")[0].innerHTML
```

You might want to fix it. One clue is it should be 'response' instead of 'reponse'.

Comment: That was dumb from me , i thought this would fix it but it didnt, i think the issue may come from the $_POST i'm using in my function that gets my sql query result , it would mean it doesnt find result for the query with the parameter given(the value in the selected item in dropdown list) but i somehow cant identify where this comes from

Comment: after thinking it cant be the $_POST since doing an alert(xhr.ResponseText) gives me my xml with the good values from database so the $_POST do get the information from the dropdown list